# How to permanently draw things in OpenGL's Immediate mode?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am having a small problem in essentially creating a path tracer.

In my project, I have an object which constantly moves around quite organically through an update function done in the while loop. I use immediate mode and represent the player as a square, I would like to make it so that every update the object is drawn in its current position, but also for it to draw it's previous position(s), so etching dots towards the path the object is going. I'm pretty sure we can do this by drawing the position as normal but not clearing everything up after this instance in the while loop, but I have no knowledge on how to do this.

Edit: For those who want the code, do understand that this code, in particular, is not adherent to the question and that I made a ton of generalizations (such as the particle(s) being referred to an object) so that the general gist of the question is understandable:

```
#include "PerlinNoise.hpp"
#include "Particle.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace siv;

float map(float oValue, float oMin, float oMax, float nMin, float nMax)
{
  float oRange = (oMax - oMin);
  float nRange = (nMax - nMin);
  return(((oValue - oMin) * nRange)/oRange) + nMin;
}

void drawRectangle(float x, float y, float xr, float yr, float R, float G, float B)
{
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glColor3f(R,G,B);
  glVertex2f(x,y);
  glVertex2f(x+xr,y);
  glVertex2f(x+xr,y+yr);
  glVertex2f(x,y+yr);
  glEnd();
}

void drawLine(float x, float y, float xr, float yr, float rotation)
{
  float radius = sqrt(xr*xr + yr*yr);
  float a0 = asin(yr/radius);
  float tangle = a0+rotation;
  //std::cout<<tangle*180/M_PI<<std::endl;
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glColor3f(.1,.1,.1);
  glVertex2f(x,y);
  glVertex2f(x + sin(tangle)*radius,y + cos(tangle)*radius);
  glEnd();
}


int main()
{
  float inc = 0.1;
  int scl   = 20;
  int cols,rows;

  Particle particles[100000];

  //V2D flowfield[cols*rows];

  GLFWwindow* window;
  if (!glfwInit())
    return 1;
  int width  = 800;
  int height = 800;
  window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Window", NULL, NULL);
  cols = floor(width/scl);
  rows = floor(height/scl);
  V2D flowfield[cols*rows];
  float zoff = 0;
  if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    return 1;
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  if(glewInit()!=GLEW_OK)
    std::cout<<"Error"<<std::endl;
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
  glOrtho(0, width*(width/height), height, 0, -2, 2);
  PerlinNoise png = PerlinNoise(1);
  while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.11, 0.14, 0.17, 1);
    float yoff = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
    {
      float xoff = 0;
      for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
      {
        double noise = map(png.noise((double)xoff, (double)yoff, (double)zoff),-1,1,0,1);
        double angle = noise * 8 *M_PI;
        //std::cout<<angle/(2*M_PI)<<std::endl;
        int index = x + y * cols;
        V2D v = V2D(cos(angle), sin(angle));
        v.normalize();
        v = V2D(v.x*5,v.y*5);
        flowfield[index] = v;
        //drawLine(x*scl, y*scl, scl, 0, atan2(v.x, v.y));
        //drawRectangle(x*scl,y*scl,scl,scl,noise,noise,noise);

        xoff += inc;
      }
      yoff += inc;
      zoff += 0.0001;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
      particles[i].follow(flowfield);
      particles[i].update();
      particles[i].show();
    }
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: Show your current draw loop?

Comment: @Botje Are u sure it is a very big chunk of code, and a lot of things I said were generalizations so that the question was understandable.

Comment: Presumably you already tried not calling `glClear` every frame, so you will need to show a minimal example we can comment on.

Comment: @Botje It has been edited to include the code.

Comment: Simply remove `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` from your glClear call?

Comment: @Botje This does indeed work, however the program glitches sometimes(the pixels shift quite vigorously), is this normal?

Comment: That is probably caused by double buffering. [Ask GLFW to switch to single buffering](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/415), or do your drawing in a headless framebuffer (that you never clear) and on every frame overwrite the main framebuffer with the contents of the headless framebuffer. The first option is probably less work, at the expense of slower drawing.

Comment: @Botje Thanks for the info I will mark this as Solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When drawing directly to a window (be it double buffered or not doesn't make a difference) you must not make any assumptions about its contents being persistent between drawing. Heck, strictly speaking the contents may become damaged mid draw, before things even finished up; of course in practice this isn't very likely to happen and given modern compositing graphics systems it's practically eliminated.

Your application screams for drawing to an intermediary framebuffer object. FBOs are guaranteed to retain their contents no matter what happens; also you can add further drawing to the backing buffer of an FBO at any time.

The official OpenGL wiki describes FBOs at https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object

Also ages ago I wrote a simple codesample (using a lot of outdated, legacy OpenGL); drawing is legacy, but the FBO parts are done today as it was 10 years ago: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/minimalfbo/minimalfbo.c (I implemented it using render to texture; a render to renderbuffer and buffer blit to main framebuffer would work for you, too).